# BouncyCastleProvider used in KeyStore causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore

Using the BKS in place of the JKS seems to cause a StackOverflowError.

I'm trying to figure out why the call to setKeyEntry causes BouncyCastle's SecureRandom implementation to break and how to fix it, any ideas?

I have inserted the BouncyCastleProvider Security provider list into the "first" position using `Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);`. BC version 1.57.

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
//  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); // this works
    ks.load(null, null);
    ks.setKeyEntry("serverEC", privateKey, "password".toCharArray(), new X509Certificate[]{ certEC, caCertEC });
```

The stacktrace I get is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.engineSetSeed(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(SecureRandom.java:427)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.SP800SecureRandom.setSeed(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.engineSetSeed(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(SecureRandom.java:427)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.SP800SecureRandom.setSeed(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.engineSetSeed(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(SecureRandom.java:427)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.SP800SecureRandom.setSeed(Unknown Source)
....
```

Comment: "I have inserted the BouncyCastleProvider Security provider list into the "first" position using Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);". What happens if you *don't* do that?